# LDAP search user based on certificate in Linux command line

Tags: linux, ldap, ldap-query

I want to search a user using ldapsearch, but the hosting provider gave me a certificate from the CA. I added that certificate in my ldapconf.

Before executing the `ldapsearch` command I am running `openssl` as follows

```
openssl s_client -connect hostname -CAfile /certificate.pem
```

After connecting via `openssl`, I execute the following command in another terminal

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p portno -D uid=mailid@domain.con, dc=global,dc=example,dc=net
```

Now I want to know, is there any way to use the certificate while executing the `ldapsearch` command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should be doable by performing:

```
env LDAPTLS_CACERT=/certificate.pem ldapsearch -h hostname -p portno -D uid=mailid@domain.con, dc=global,dc=example,dc=net
```

although, I'd use:

```
env LDAPTLS_CACERT=/certificate.pem ldapsearch -H ldaps://hostname:portno/ -D uid=mailid@domain.con, dc=global,dc=example,dc=net
```

to ensure that it tries with ldaps, rather than heuristics.

If you're getting errors still, you can add `-ZZ` which will give better error messages.

An obvious gotcha is using an expired cert, the second most obvious gotcha is not using the same name in the request as you've got in the certificate. You can read the server cert using `openssl s_client -connect hostname:portno` - there will be a line reading something like:

```
subject=/C=IE/CN=hostname.domain.local
```

you have to ensure that the ldapsearch request's hostname matches the hostname as listed in the `CN=...` item. If it doesn't match then you'll not be able to connect (this is simple cert validation, if there are alternative names then you can try: `openssl x509 -text -noout -in /certificate.pem | grep DNS`)

A final caveat is that Mac OSX does not respect the `LDAPTLS_CACERT` environment variable. You have to import the cert into the keychain (I don't know of a workaround for OSX in this case).

Comment: Thanks @Petesh. But When I tried this command getting error as ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

Comment: First, make sure that the file is being read - use strace to verify that the file is being opened. You can also try with the `-ZZ` option which should give better debugging information. A typical error would be something like `TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate` (i.e. you're not using the same hostname as supplied in the cert). You can check the CN using `openssl s_client -connect hostname:portno` - check for the line reading `subject=` for the `CN=`, and you have to use that as the hostname.

Comment: @Petesh Thanks a lot. Your answer saved my day.

Comment: Another big thanks from me @Petesh you saved the day.